# How to get the current and local date and time in Django?

Tags: python, django, datetime, django-views

I want to get the local time, so I tried the following codes in my Django shell.

```
from django.utils import timezone

now = timezone.localtime(timezone.now())
date = now.date()
time = now.time()
##
from datetime import datetime
now = datetime.now()
>>> print(now)
datetime.datetime(2021, 7, 15, 4, 13, 49, 624395)
```

In both cases, I got the wrong time, but if I use the same code in my terminal as python code, I get the current and local time.

```
>>> datetime.now()
datetime.datetime(2021, 7, 15, 8, 22, 50, 316528)
>>>
```

Comment: Actually, Not It doesn't work for me.

Comment: Please extend your question with what is not working in the other question, your timezone, the timezone of the machine, the timezone set in Django and your expected result.

Comment: Did you set correct `TIME_ZONE` in settings?

Comment: As I mentioned in the question, the problem I think is in Django not in the machine. I try the same code in my Django shell and python terminal, but I got two different result.

Comment: Yes my machine time zone is correct